# Redux-Saga not rendering when Redux-Devtools is disabled

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I am using redux-saga to populate my state with the result and then redirect them to the next page

```
function* postSearchAction(action) {
  yield put(loadingAction(true));
  let result;
  try {
    result = yield call(request, `${process.env.API_URL}result`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(action.form),
    });

    yield put(loadResult(result));
    yield put(loadingAction(false));
    yield put(history.push('/result'));
  } catch (err) {
    // Do Nothing for now
  }
}


export default function* homeSaga() {
  yield takeLatest(SUBMIT_FORM, postSearchAction);
}
```

The odd thing is that this works whenever Redux-Devtools is running on the browser. When I deploy it as production (devtools disabled) or running it on incognito without the tools on Dev mode - I will get the `loadAction` and `history.push` to work, but my result is not rendered.

any clues as to why this is happening??

Answer (score 0):

Found out the problem.

I was using the react-boiler plate, and they are using `useInjectReduceron` each containers. My action was not being registered by the reducer from the original container since the action belongs to another container, it did not actually get dispatched.

I am not sure why it works when devtool is used, maybe it maintains the reducers along the way.